# Merging lines that has duplicates and summing last column

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pandas

I have this input text file

```
1;2;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;5;

1;2;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;3;

1;3;02.02.2017;09.00-10.00;4;

1;3;03.02.2017;12.00-13.00;2;

1;3;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;6;

1;3;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;3;

1;3;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;2;

1;3;29.02.2017;11.00-12.00;2;

1;3;29.02.2017;12.00-13.00;3;

10;11;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;6;

10;11;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;1;

10;12;02.02.2017;09.00-10.00;8;

10;12;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;2;

10;12;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;1;
```

values separated by ';' are as follows:
1- id_1(str), 2- id_2(str), 3- date(str), 4- time(str), 5- area(int)

As output, I need a text file that contains lines from input, that have 1,2,3,4 duplicates and the sum of area. I need lines without duplicates to be dropped, e.g.

```
1;2;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;8;  (sum of 5 from line 1 and 3 from line 2)

1;3;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;5;

10;11;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;7;

10;12;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;3;
```

What I achieved so far, is getting dropped lines without duplicates, but I had to remove the area column.

I used this:

```
seen = set()
for line1 in imp:
    line1_lower = line1.lower()
    if line1_lower in seen:
        print(line1)
    else:
        seen.add(line1_lower)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) first with parameter `names` for create column names (if `csv` have no header):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""1;2;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;5;
1;2;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;3;
1;3;02.02.2017;09.00-10.00;4;
1;3;03.02.2017;12.00-13.00;2;
1;3;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;6;
1;3;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;3;
1;3;29.02.2017;10.00-11.00;2;
1;3;29.02.2017;11.00-12.00;2;
1;3;29.02.2017;12.00-13.00;3;
10;11;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;6;
10;11;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;1;
10;12;02.02.2017;09.00-10.00;8;
10;12;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;2;
10;12;28.02.2017;08.00-09.00;1;"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", names=['id_1','id_2','date','time','area','tmp'])
```

```
print (df)
    id_1  id_2        date         time  area  tmp
0      1     2  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00     5  NaN
1      1     2  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00     3  NaN
2      1     3  02.02.2017  09.00-10.00     4  NaN
3      1     3  03.02.2017  12.00-13.00     2  NaN
4      1     3  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     6  NaN
5      1     3  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00     3  NaN
6      1     3  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00     2  NaN
7      1     3  29.02.2017  11.00-12.00     2  NaN
8      1     3  29.02.2017  12.00-13.00     3  NaN
9     10    11  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     6  NaN
10    10    11  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     1  NaN
11    10    12  02.02.2017  09.00-10.00     8  NaN
12    10    12  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     2  NaN
13    10    12  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     1  NaN
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `size` and `sum`, last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for remove duplicates - get values where size is greater as `1`:

```
cols = ['id_1','id_2','date','time']
df = df.groupby(cols)['area'].agg(['size', 'sum'])
df = df[df['size'] > 1].drop('size',axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id_1  id_2        date         time  sum
0     1     2  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00    8
1     1     3  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00    5
2    10    11  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00    7
3    10    12  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00    3
```

Another solution is remove duplicates first by `boolean indexing` with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
cols = ['id_1','id_2','date','time']
mask = df.duplicated(cols, keep=False)
df = df[mask].groupby(cols, as_index=False)['area'].sum()
print (df)
   id_1  id_2        date         time  area
0     1     2  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00     8
1     1     3  29.02.2017  10.00-11.00     5
2    10    11  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     7
3    10    12  28.02.2017  08.00-09.00     3
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply, I'll check it asap:) hope it will work because I have spent quite a bit of time thinking about it